# PhpStorm short tags indentation (if/endif)

Tags: coding-style, phpstorm

Here is the indentation that PhpStorm will generate for this code:

```
<?php if (count($foo) > 0) : ?>
<div>...</div>
<?php else : ?>
<p>...</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is that supposed to be the wanted PHP indentation when mixing if/for/... blocks with HTML or is it a bug with the short tags?

**I am talking about PhpStorm default formatting style.** I am wondering if this behavior is intended by PhpStorm or a bug.

Comment: There is no standard PHP indentation. There's only groups with opinions on how it SHOULD be. Indentation is one of the major causes of religious warfare in computing circles, because everyone asserts their way is The One True Way, and everyone else is a doodiehead.

Comment: Indenting isn't required in PHP, so *any and all* indentation will always be user preference, which sometimes leaks over into programs (like this) people build.

Comment: I follow the convention that braces are used in controllers, colons are used in templates. The latter is helpful as `endif` (and all the similar ones for various code blocks) is easier to spot than a closing brace. However I would definitely have tab indentation in the example you've given - perhaps you can edit the template in PhpStorm? Edit: oh yes, and the trailing semicolon on the `endif` is unnecessary.

Comment: You could use a templating engine, as per @lubnah's suggestion, but there is a body of opinion amongst PHP users that PHP is a perfectly good templating engine in itself.

Comment: @MarcB Wow slow down, I'm just talking about the PhpStorm automatic formatting... I don't want to start a flame war. I removed the [php] tag if that can prevent such reactions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final answer is that is a bug, if you expect (as anyone would I guess) the content of the `if` to be indented.

I filed a bug: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11118.

Answer (score -2):

[@Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) is actually spot on with why PHPStorm is doing it this way by default. There is no standard and therefore the PHPStorm authors just chose whatever they wanted by default and gave you **settings** where you can configure it do be however **you** want.

To answer your specific question though, it's not a bug, because there's no **correct** way for it to be. It's all personal preference.

Answer (score -3):

Neither option (braces versus if : else : endif;) is particularly readable.  If that's a priority for you, try using a templating engine instead, and encapsulate most (if not all) logic out of the template files.

Some templating engines I've used are [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) and [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), but there are a bunch out there.

Comment: I'm not talking about braces versus `if :`, I'm asking about the HTML indentation.

Comment: The original question was unclear; not sure how my answer warrants a downvote b/c of it